# How to properly paste in bash?

Tags: bash, vim, paste

Whenever I am copying over multiline sections of code, the copy and paste breaks them up into separate lines.

for example if I were to copy the following text;

```
    printf"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "
```

it would separate it into two lines.

I am copy by highlighting and pasting with shift+insert.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you not just highlight it with the mouse ?

Comment: What terminal do you use? Some terminals are configurable and allow for ignoring newlines.

Comment: @choroba Unfortunately, I'm using PuTTY.

Comment: @jidder When I highlight it with the mouse it copies, but when I go to paste it makes everything that should be on the same line a new line

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a clipboard feature interacts with (presumably) a terminal. It is about general computing hardware and software and thus is better suited to http://superuser.com (but I wanted to be clearer than the built-in close comment).

Comment: -1 Unclear.  Your question is tagged with [bash] and [vim], but you are talking about copying and pasting with the mouse in PuTTY, so it's not a bash or a vim question.

Comment: notice the text "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming".  I use vi for my Unix programming, so I certainly think this is on-topic. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

If you use vim (as you tagged), do `yy` to copy and `p` to paste.

Comment: That only works for one line, I think. I'm pasting multiple different functions of varying line length.

Comment: `Shift-V`, `jjjj` (until you have selected all the lines to copy), `y`, then `p`.

Comment: @OldMopMan #yy and p, where # is the number of lines you would like to copy.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks, I can yank all the lines I need. It says 125 lines yanked, but when I press it doesnt paste what I copied

Comment: "125yy" yanks 125 lines starting from the line where your cursor is located and "p" pastes the lines from the line next to your cursor.  Both actions have to be performed in vim command mode.

Answer (score 2):

If your vim has system clipboard support, use `"+p"`, which pastes from the `+` (system clipboard) register.

If not, you can enable paste mode with `:set paste`, make your paste, and then disable `:set nopaste`.